# Appended childs innerHTML is set to a message that involves keeping count of number of times button was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, counter

So I am working with a DOM challenge to improve my skills. I have reached the deliverable but would like to additionally only have 1 instance of each logged number run with the count increasing in that single string.

With what I have so far below, for each time my heart button is clicked during whichever count is present it will record and append that count as an li to my ul.likes.

How would I post only one li for each individual count and update the button click count within said specific li?

JS

```
const counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
const likes = document.querySelector(".likes");

function startCounter() {
  setInterval(() => {
    counter.textContent++;
  }, 1000);
}

const minus = document.querySelector("#minus");
minus.addEventListener("click", () => {
  counter.textContent--;
});

const plus = document.querySelector("#plus");
plus.addEventListener("click", () => {
  counter.textContent++;
});

let lookup = {};

function buttonClicked() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");

  let activeCount = counter.textContent;
  let likeList = document.querySelector("li");

  if (lookup[activeCount]) {
    lookup[activeCount]++;
  } else lookup[activeCount] = 1;

  li.innerHTML = `${activeCount} has been liked ${lookup[activeCount]} times!`;

  likes.appendChild(li);
  console.log(likes);
}

const heart = document.querySelector("#heart");
heart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  buttonClicked();
});

const pause = document.querySelector("#pause");

startCounter();
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dom Challenge</title>
  <style>
    #counter {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      display: table;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Welcome to the DOM Challenge
  </h1>
  <h1 id='counter'>
    0
  </h1>
  <button id='minus'> ➖ </button>
  <button id='plus'> ➕ </button>
  <button id='heart'> ❤️ </button>
  <button id='pause'> pause </button>

  <ul class='likes'></ul>

  <div>
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <div id='list' class='comments'></div>

    <h3>Leave a comment</h3>

    <form id="comment-form" action="">
      <input type='text' name="comment" id="comment-input" cols="30" rows="10">
      </br>
      <button id='submit'>submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

  <!--<script src="js/index.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/challenge.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function buttonClicked() { 
  // Create an array of all the current li items 
  const like_list = likes.getElementsByTagName('li');

  let activeCount = counter.textContent;

  // incremet by default
  if (lookup[activeCount]) {
    lookup[activeCount]++;
  } else lookup[activeCount] = 1;

  //search each li element and if the id of that element matched the activeCount update its innerHTML
  for(var i =0;i<like_list.length;i++){
     if(like_list[i].id == activeCount){
       like_list[i].innerHTML = `${activeCount} has been liked ${lookup[activeCount]} times!`;
       return;
     }
  }

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = `${activeCount} has been liked ${lookup[activeCount]} times!`;
  //set the id attribute of new li elements
  li.setAttribute("id", activeCount);
  likes.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: this is awesome and really mind blowing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).